# Stop Visual Studio Code from opening files on exception

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

While debugging a Flutter app, Visual Studio Code opens up files where exceptions happen even if I uncheck breakpoints for "All Exceptions" and "Uncaught Exceptions" in the debug pane. I even removed all breakpoints. Is there a way to disable this?

I couldn't find anything in settings. It's super frustrating to be editing a file and all of a sudden another file pops up and now I'm inadvertently editing some Dart system library.

A few files I've seen opened by the editor are `binding.dart`, `view.dart`, `clip.dart`, and `sha256.dart`, off the top of my head.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's so annoying ...

Comment: Never did, sadly :(

Comment: some things that I tried that DON'T work (in settings.json): "debug.focusWindowOnBreak": false, "debug.focusEditorOnBreak": false